# Ionic3 super starter ngx-translation not working on android real device

Tags: ionic3

i just downloaded and instaled ionic super starter template, and, the translation is working perfectly on the browser, but when i install the android apk on my device the translation does not work. i did not make many changes on the code, i am studing how to use it on my project. Any help about that?
I am from Brazil and it was supposed to bring me the Portuguese(pt-BR).
Thanks.

Comment: Try import tranlation from 'src/app/..' And not from '.. /..

Comment: hi my friend, I did not understand what you sayd. i have to do it in which page? app.copmponent or app.module? remember that i did not change anything on the ionic super starter template code.

Comment: the default import code in the app.module.ts :                                                
 export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

Comment: have you tagged the question incorrectly? The super starter is an ionic 3 starter and not updated for ionic 4 yet as far as I know.

Comment: @rtpHarry man thanks you very much, i researched here and you are right. so this way, i have to search a way for solving this question with ionic3. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, the ionic super starter template cames with the i18n folder with many languages in json format, in my case, the device is returning the pt-BR language, and should use 'pr-BR.json' file. but the i18n language that cames with ionic, the portuguese file is pt-br (in lower case). i just renamed this file to 'pr-BR' (lower case) and its working now. thanks you every one who contributed.